# A word for something that is too visible?

Tags: word-choice, word-meaning, word-request, idiomatic-language

How to call something/someone that is too visible, more that it/she should or deserves, or more than it is natural and accepted? The word I have in mind is "over-visible". Are **over-visible** and **over-visibility** correct/idiomatic words?

I want to say that someone is too visible, as in the following sentence:

> Unlike philosophers who suffer from invisibility in the society, sociologists enjoy over-visibility.

Is the use of "over-visibility" in the above sentence correct?

Comment: Can you add an example sentence, and maybe clarify your request? There are lots of words that could fit.

Comment: Do you literally mean [visible](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/visible) (_capable of being seen_)? Or do you mean someone who is more popular or famous than they deserve? Maybe you're thinking of [overrated](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/overrated)

Comment: What do you mean by "too visible"?  *Visible* is a binary word -- something either *can* be seen or it *can't* be seen, period.

Comment: **showy**, **ostentatious**, **obtrusive** -- take your pick.

Comment: The short answer is no, **over-visible** is not idiomatic. This why people are confused about what you mean by "over-visible."

Answer (score 2):

The most common term would be overexposure. In such a context, it means what you are trying to say.

Answer (score 1):

It depends what you mean by

> **too visible**

A revealing dress can make the wearer **too visible**.
If an animal which uses camouflage in the forest is on a beach, it can be **too visible**.

Possibly the word you are looking for is

> **overexposed**

which can describe *something* which has been *very visible for too long*.

Comment: What about words over-visible or over-visibility?

Comment: Have you looked those words up? I don't think they are real words.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best word for something that is "too visible" is:

> Conspicuous.

Maybe you're familiar with its antonym *inconspicuous*, which is normally used to describe someone or something that blends in with the surroundings to the point of being unseen. As you would expect "conspicuous" means that something is very easily seen, attracting notice or attention.

These two words have more depth of meaning than *visible* and *invisible*, which solely focus on whether or not something *can* or *cannot* possibly be seen. *Conspicuous* adds the meaning that something is readily noticeable, perhaps more than intended.

Answer (score 0):

With regards to your example, the word "prominent"/"prominence" comes to mind (though it doesn't actually mean *too* visible, so we'd have to add that in). It's also quite a sophisticated/erudite statement, and so I'd probably phrase it something like:

> Unlike philosophers, who suffer a degree of invisibility in society, sociologists enjoy perhaps a little too much prominence.